# Get values from multidimensional array PhP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, php-5.5

I have an array with products (each product has more arrays)

I want to get the values ["0_1"] or ["0_2"]? 
If it starts with 0 it should send that product to the end of the array

```
array(14) { 
    ["0_1"]=> array(27) {
        ["files"]=> array(0) { } 
        ["images"]=> array(0) { } 
        ["form_addtocart"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["has_addtocart"]=> bool(false) 
        ["product_flypage"]=> string(137) "index.php?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage.tpl&product_id=3299&category_id=88&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=2"
        ["product_thumb_image"]=> string(170) "http://www.e-theodoulidis.gr/components/com_virtuemart/show_image_in_imgtag.php?filename=General_Electric_4e5f4d8265044.jpg&newxsize=120&newysize=120&fileout="
        ["product_full_image"]=> string(108) "http://www.e-theodoulidis.gr/components/com_virtuemart/shop_image/product/General_Electric_4e5f4d8265044.jpg"
        ["full_image_width"]=> int(1064)
        ["full_image_height"]=> int(1064)
        ["product_name"]=> string(42) "General Electric Τηλέγωνο CE 30044"
        ["product_s_desc"]=> string(0) ""
        ["product_details"]=> string(43) "Λεπτομέρειες προϊόντος"
        ["product_rating"]=> string(0) ""
        ["product_price"]=> string(344) " Καλέστε για Τιμή "
        ["product_price_raw"]=> array(1) { 
            ["product_price"]=> float(0)
        }
        ["product_sku"]=> string(25) "General Electric CE 30044"
        ["product_weight"]=> string(6) "0.0000"
        ["product_weight_uom"]=> string(2) "kg"
        ["product_length"]=> string(6) "0.0000"
        ["product_width"]=> string(6) "0.0000"
        ["product_height"]=> string(6) "0.0000"
        ["product_lwh_uom"]=> string(6) "inches"
        ["product_in_stock"]=> string(1) "0"
        ["product_availability_date"]=> NULL
        ["product_availability"]=> string(0) ""
        ["cdate"]=> string(10) "1314868610"
        ["mdate"]=> string(10) "1314868610"
    }
    ["0_2"]=> array(27) {
        ["files"]=> array(0) { }
        ["images"]=> array(0) { }
        ["form_addtocart"]=> string(0) ""
        ["has_addtocart"]=> bool(false)
        ["product_flypage"]=> string(137) "index.php?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage.tpl&product_id=7609&category_id=88&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=2"
        ["product_thumb_image"]=> string(188) "http://www.e-theodoulidis.gr/components/com_virtuemart/show_image_in_imgtag.php?filename=resized%2FPanasonic________533a7b4f573b0_120x120.jpg&newxsize=120&newysize=120&fileout="
        ["product_full_image"]=> string(108) "http://www.e-theodoulidis.gr/components/com_virtuemart/shop_image/product/Panasonic________533a7b4f5cba6.jpg"
        ["full_image_width"]=> int(530)
        ["full_image_height"]=> int(403)
        ["product_name"]=> string(39) "Panasonic Τηλέφωνο KX-TS560EX2B"
        ["product_s_desc"]=> string(0) ""
        ["product_details"]=> string(43) "Λεπτομέρειες προϊόντος"
        ["product_rating"]=> string(0) ""
        ["product_price"]=> string(339) " Καλέστε για Τιμή "
        ["product_price_raw"]=> array(1) {
            ["product_price"]=> float(0)
        }
        ["product_sku"]=> string(22) "Panasonic KX-TS560EX2B"
        ["product_weight"]=> string(6) "0.0000"
        ["product_weight_uom"]=> string(2) "kg"
        ["product_length"]=> string(6) "0.0000"
        ["product_width"]=> string(6) "0.0000"
        ["product_height"]=> string(6) "0.0000"
        ["product_lwh_uom"]=> string(6) "inches"
        ["product_in_stock"]=> string(1) "0"
        ["product_availability_date"]=> NULL
        ["product_availability"]=> string(0) ""
        ["cdate"]=> string(10) "1396341583"
        ["mdate"]=> string(10) "1426577025"
    }
}
```

Comment: if you properly format/indent that dump, each layer of indentation is basically another key to add to your path. and `0_1` in your array is a key, not a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those on the left (eg. "0_1") are the array keys, and the values are the ones on the right.

To get just the keys, use:

```
$arrayOfKeys = array_keys($array)
```

or to iterate over each item, use:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) { }
```